# How to build an installer file for Linux from a released project

Tags: linux

I've built a project and released it. Now I want to have have an insatller file of this released version for Linux. On Windows I've used Inno Setup and got my installer file, but on I cannot find the proper way to do this on Linux... Can anyone help please?

Comment: Different Linux distributions use different package managers, so you have to specifiy for which distribution(s) you want to create the installer. If your project is Python only, then you can consider using `pip`. If your project is open source then one way might be use use `automake` (which allows the user to do `configure`, `make`, `make install` to build your project locally).

Comment: I am actually using Qt I released my project and it created its own Makefile within the Release folder but I'm struggling to get my installer from there